# Determining if a new series converges knowing the convergence of a previous series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am unsure how to approach this question: [image: picture]

> A series of the form $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty c_n$ is known to converge. If each $c_n$ may have values that are positive or negative, which one of the following statments must also **always$$ be true:
>
> I) $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nc_n$ must converge
>   II) $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{c_n}{2^n}$ must converge
>   III) $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty 2^nc_n$ must converge

I have tried using the limit comparison test, but I get an answer of 0, so I cannot yield anything from it. How do I approach determining if these series containing the series cn are also convergent or not?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get answers rather than downvotes if you edit the question so that it shows the mathematics, not an image, shows your work, and asks just one question at a time (your picture has several). Use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I. Is not necessarily true. Consider $c_n=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}$, then

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^nc_n &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{2n}}{n}\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}
\end{align}
$$

which diverges.

II. Is true.

III. Is not necessarily true. Take $c_n = \frac{1}{2^{n^2}}$, then

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^n\frac{1}{2^{n^2}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}
$$

which converges.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I understand your reasoning for I. and III. but can you elaborate on how you deduced II is true? Is there a test I can use?

Comment: Dividing each term by $2^n$ only makes each term smaller. So if $c_n$ converges, $\frac{c_n}{2^n}$ must converge too.